How to recover a COMPLETE binary tree from inorder, preorder or postorder traversal (uniquely! from only one traversal)
it's a common problem in CS/Data Structures/Graph Theory to recover a tree (or even binary tree) uniquely from a given set of inorder, preorder or postorder traversals. There is no method in general to find a unique solution from one type of traversal alone for arbitrary trees (or even binary trees), however, there is a unique solution for this problem with one traversal only when the binary tree is a complete binary tree: that is, a binary tree where each level is full except maybe the last level, where the level is completed in the leftmost part.
I was stuck with this problem for homework and didn't found a solution with pseudocode nowhere until I found one myself, this is why I decided to create this question (and why I'll answer it myself). I hope someone finds this useful.

So here's the proposed solution: in fact, this will work with any kind of traversal of the tree, as long as the traversal is known and replicable, the traversal is deterministic (there's no randomness, the final traversal will be the same always if we start from the same tree), it lists all nodes and no nodes are visited twice.
Let $L = [l_0, l_1, \ldots, l_{n-1}]$ be a list of $n$ elements consisting on the traversal of some unknown complete binary tree $T_{unk}$. The key idea in here is that the complete binary tree with $n$ nodes is unique, in shape at least (values in each node might vary, but the shape overall is uniquely determined by the number of nodes). For simplicity and compatibility with Python, we will arbitrarily decide lists begin on index 0.
The second step is to generate a complete binary tree $T$ of $n$ nodes, where each node has a numeric (integer) value (or key) in the following way: the root has key 0, the two nodes in the second level have keys 1 and 2, the four nodes in the third level have keys 3, 4, 5 and 6... and so on, eventually reaching the last node of the complete binary tree, with key $n-1$ (there are $n$ nodes in total). Like this:
$n$ nodes where we begin from 0 n the root, all the way up to $n-1$" />
As you can see, we can easily construct $T$ from the list $[0,1,2,\ldots,n-1]$ in a orderly fashion, assigning keys to each node in a linear way from the list.
Since $T$ is a complete binary tree with $n$ nodes, $T$ has the same shape of $T_{unk}$, the unknown complete binary tree of which we only know the traversal list we have to begin with. Thus, there exists a bijection from the elements of the list $[0,1,2,\ldots,n-1]$ to the elements of $L$ (we can suppose each element is unique without loss of generality: if the elements of $L$ are not distinct, we can consider the list $L'$ formed like this: $L' = [(l_0, 0),\ldots,(l_i, i), \ldots, (l_{n-1}, n-1)]$. Each element of $L'$ is unique, and to recover the original value of $L$ on index $i$, we just take the first component of the $i$-th element of $L'$).
We then perform the traversal on $T$ to get the list $\Lambda = [\lambda_0, \lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_{n-1}]$, which is a permutation of $[0,1,\ldots,n-1]$. By the hypothesis, the traversal is deterministic so the tree $T_{unk}$ was subjected to the same traversal to produce $L$ (for example: inorder, preorder or postorder).
The list $\Lambda$ has a bijection $\lambda$ associated with it, from $[0,1,\ldots,n-1]$ to $[\lambda_0,\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_{n-1}]$, namely: $\lambda(i) = \lambda_i$. Thus, we can invert it and then $\lambda^{-1} (\lambda_i) = i$. Remember that $0\leq \lambda_i \leq n-1$ for $0\leq i\leq n-1$.
We're pretty much done now. If $0\leq i\leq n-1$, there exists $0\leq j\leq n-1$ such that $i = \lambda_j$. This means that the $i$-th element of $T$ ends up in position $j$ of $\Lambda$. Thus, position $j$ of $\Lambda$ corresponds with the $i$-th node of $T$. We use that to reconstruct $T_{unk}$: if $i = \lambda_j$, then $l_j$ is the $i$-th element of $T_{unk}$, where we index elements of $T_{unk}$ beginning from 0 (the root) all the way up to $n-1$ (the last one).
By linearly traversing the list $L$ and assigning $l_j$ to the $i$-th node (where $\lambda_j = i$), we uniquely determine all values of the nodes of $T_{unk}$. This solves the problem.
